# Knife throw in final leap-of-faith

Tags: realism, assassins-creed

During the final leap-of-faith in *[Assassin's Creed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2094766/)*, the main character (Aguilar) visibly throws a knife at the water he is about to jump in to, presumably to break the water.

Is this possible, as in, would you be able to do this to avoid serious injuries from jumping in water from such height?

Comment: For reference [this clip](https://youtu.be/XPCihjOrus8?t=3m6s) shows the jump

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.
There is [an old mythbusters episode](http://mythresults.com/episode5) on this.

> "Dropping a hammer in front of you may break the surface tension, but
>   it will not save your life because water is still too viscous to move
>   out of the way quickly."

Haven't seen the actual movie, but if the jump is high enough to kill you when you hit the water, it will still kill you if you throw something in the water.

Comment: However, in 1492 when that jump was made (in universe) Aguilar did not have a TV and did not have the Mythbusters to tell him it was pointless. While I am no historian, I do know that swimming ability was rare back then and science was not what it is today. That scene very well could be more accurate than anything else in the movie, in the sense that people of the day who could swim may have thought "breaking the water" before diving in would soften the blow.

Comment: @snowman No matter what the character thought would happen, the knife does nothing to stop reality. assuming physics and anatomy are the same as real world, a jump from that height would kill, knife or no knife.

Comment: @cde I agree, my point is a person in 1492 would not know any better, and the movie portrayed it that way whether purposefully or not.

Answer (score 0):

Aguilar falls for around 8 seconds, which means (I am unable to know for sure, given that he falls in multiple positions), that he would be falling at 90% of terminal velocity. He would probably not survive. However, he would have fallen about 1029 feet, nearly a quarter mile. As far as I can tell, there was no such bridge in Spain, as the highest i can find is around 120 feet (at least that is in a similar location (it is in Rhonda)). Therefore, the jump was either cinematically slowed to accentuate Aguilar's acrobatics, or it is just ignoring historical construction. Either way, it is an epic sequence, which I enjoy very much. Perhaps the filmmakers made the jump farther in order to make the audience feel more of an impact while watching, as falls in movies seem less consequential.

Answer (score -3):

It's just a MOVIE! Of course it's exaggerated to entertain! If you just go by what "IS" technically possible? 7× outta 10 it's going to be not near as exciting! (depending on the type of movie) Listen... I'm a HUGE "AC" fan, & I know there has NEVER been a video game based film that's been no better than "OK", like this 1 ("Assassin's Creed"). Whether it's good, outstanding, bad, or just decent? If your going to make a video game movie? It's going to HAVE to be exaggerated.